# Maximizing $l_1$-normalized entropy using CVXPY

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, cvxpy

Suppose that $x = (x_1, ..., x_n)$ is a vector of variables and I would like to maximize the Shannon entropy of $\frac{|x|}{||x||_1}$ (i.e. the vector of absolute values of $x_i$, normalized to have $l_1$ norm = 1) subject to some linear constraints. However, this function is not directly expressible as a composition of atoms recognized by CVXPY as convex/concave (although CVXPY recognizes entropy itself). Are there any tricks to write this program in a way suitable for CVXPY?

Comment: What is the "abs value of $x$", $|x|$? Do you mean the $l_2$ norm?

Comment: Edited to clarify.

Comment: Then can you define what the Shannon entropy of a vector is?

Comment: Are you able to prove the function is convex?

Comment: Maybe use a general purpose NLP solver instead.